# Dimension analysis, check for equation homogeneity

Tags: java

Is there a way in Java to check for operation homogeneity ? Does an existing library do that ?

As an example, if I declare some members to be of some dimension like this:

```
class MyClass {
    @Quantity("Speed")
    double speed;

    @Quantity("Distance")
    double distance;

    @quantity("Time")
    double time;

    // Should not raise any error
    double getSpeed()
    {
        return distance / time;
    }

    // Should raise an error
    void computeTime()
    {
        time = speed * distance;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Does something close to Boost.Units (C++) exists in java ?

Comment: Why would computeTime raise an error?

Comment: Based on some of the keywords, I am guessing that you are looking for some Maths library.

Comment: @banncee because speed is distance/time and multipliying it by `distance` gives distance²/time and `time` is just time. The correct operation would have been `time = distance / speed`.
@BheshGurung more like a physics library implementing Math function in a safer way. The best library I found is Boost.Units but for C++

Comment: @dkg I meant a *syntactic* error. Not sure if what you want exists in Java. You could, I suppose, code something that looked at annotations on class variables, and had some kind of AOP to check annotated methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [JScience](http://jscience.org/) that can check for units.

Example of use here : https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/june-2006-units-and-measures-with-jscience